# Probability, Cancers and Doctors

Tags: probability

I was pondering on how to answer this question. It looks like this:

In a certain region of the country it is known from past experience that the probability of selecting an adult over 40 years of age with cancer is 0.05. If the probability of a doctor correctly diagnosing a person with cancer as having the disease is 0.78 and the probability of incorrectly diagnosing a person without cancer as having the disease is 0.06, what is the probability that a person is diagnosed as having cancer?

I thought it was very obvious that the answer above would be 0.05 because it talks about a probability that a person having a cancer is 0.05. The answer written in the book was 0.0960.

My head is messed up right now, pondering too hard on how to answer it. How do you answer it?

Does the problem above can be visualized using Venn diagrams?

Comment: Tip: "Diagnosed as having" and "Actually having" are different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $B_1, B_2, \cdots B_K$ form a "partition" (Mutually exclusive and exhaustive events). Then the Law of Total Probability States:

$$P(A) = P(A|B_1)P(B_1) + P(A|B_2)P(B_2) + \cdots P(A|B_k)P(B_k)$$

Let $C$ denote the event that a person has cancer, then obviously $C$ and $C^c$ form a partition. If we condition on these events, we can find the "marginal" probability that somebody is diagnosed with cancer (call this even $D$).

\begin{align*}
P(D) &= P(D|C)P(C) + P(D|C^c)P(C^c) \\
&= (0.78)(0.05) + (0.06)(1-.05) \\
&= .096
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean that this particular sample space would be an **region of the country**? and the particular partitions would be **adults having a cancer at over the age of 40** and the  **adults having a cancer at under the age of 40**? Did I get it right?

Comment: The partition would be, $C$ "an adult over forty has cancer" and $C^c$ is "adult over forty doesn't have cancer".

Comment: What about the sample space? What it's sample space?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. But maybe this will help. There are essentially only four events that can occur. In all four cases, when I say "adult" I mean "an adult over forty from a certain region in the country". 1) An adult has cancer, and is correctly diagnosed. 2) An adult has cancer and is incorrectly diagnosed. 3) An adult does not have cancer and is correctly diagnosed. 4) An adult does not have cancer and is incorrectly diagnosed. These four outcomes are sometimes called, "true positive", "false positive", "true negative" and "false negative".

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the distinction here between (1) having cancer and (2) being diagnosed with cancer.  The point of the exercise is that sometimes doctors can mis-diagnose.

Let's give some events some names: let $C$ be the event that a person has cancer, and let $D$ be the event that they are diagnosed with cancer.

Then the three pieces of information you're given can be rewritten as:
$$
P(C)=0.05\qquad P(D\mid C)=0.78\qquad P(D\mid\neg C)=0.06
$$
You are asked to compute $P(D)$.  I would start by using the law of total probability:
$$
P(D)=P(D\mid C)\cdot P(C)+P(D\mid \neg C)\cdot P(\neg C).
$$

Comment: As I can see in your answer, $D$ is the event that the person is diagnosed with cancer, the probability of incorrectly diagnosing a person without cancer as having the disease is $0.06$, why is it not $P(\neg D \mid C)$ instead of $P(D\mid \neg C)$? Because the person was diagnosed without cancer (which is $\neg D$) as having the disease (which is $C$).

Comment: $D$ is the event "the doctor says you have cancer". The text above says that the likelihood of being told that you DO have cancer, even though you actually do not, is $0.06$; that's precisely the meaning of $P(D\mid\neg C)$.